# add pesdk image editor to ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I came across a [photo editor cordova plugin](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com) for editing images that I want to include in my ionic 2 app. The [getting started instructions](http://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/quickstarts/ionic) by the author are kinda straight forward but cant get it working - the app keeps crashing on launch in my android phone. The code that I compiled can be found on [github](https://github.com/sigu/spike_photoeditor)

What I have done so far

1. Created a new ionic app
2. Followed through [this setup process](https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-ionic-demo#setup-process)

   ```
   $ git submodule add git@github.com:imgly/pesdk-cordova-demo.git
   $ ionic plugin add --searchpath ./pesdk-cordova-demo cordova-plugin-pesdk
   ```
3. Added the licence as suggested [here](https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-ionic-demo#launch-example)
4. Did not use emulator but compiled and installed on my phone

How do I add this plugin to an ionic 2 application? I am also flexible to other recommendations of image editors that I can use on the ionic app

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: It just crashed on my phone. I can not connect my phone to computer so I cant really log the errors, is there a way I can see the logs?

Comment: you will have to connect to a system to see the logs https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: Is there any update regarding this issue? I am also facing it.